# "bead" on a string theory of genetics, source?

Tags: genetics, gene

Thomas Hunt Morgan was a pioneer in genetics and proposed the now false model of genes being "beads" on a string. These beads being indivisible and responsible for a single phenotype, if I understand correctly.

Does anyone know of a good, reputable source of information on this theory that would be sufficient to use as a citation? I would use wikipedia, but it is disallowed.

Comment: I found [this reference](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/alumni/Magazine/Legacies/Morgan/) on the [Thomas Hunt Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Hunt_Morgan) wikipedia page. It uses the "Beads on a String" phrase and may be more appropriate material for your homework. I would recommend you read the references on the bottom of that page for more information on his work and hypotheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Cold Spring Harbor Laboratory is considered a reputable source (it should be), you can check out their [Defining the gene](http://www.dnalc.org/view/15881-Defining-the-gene.html) page which has an overview of the beads-on-a-string theory, and how it was disproved by Seymour Benzer. You could also try to find [Benzer's original paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/13293416), although it doesnt seem to be available online.

Related and possibly helpful:

- [Benzer's page](http://www.dnalc.org/view/16023-Seymour-Benzer-1954.html) on Cold Spring Harbor website
- [Evolution of Genes and Genes in Evolution](http://symposium.cshlp.org/content/24/15.extract) - very interesting paper from 1959 on genes/genetics, look on the fourth page (marked 18) for the bead-on-string theory